# Compiling All the Symbols of an Object File as Weak

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

### Motivation

I have 2 static libraries, *libStatic1.a* and *libStatic2.a*. In addition, I have many SOs (Shared Objects) that compile with libStatic1.a.
Up until now, libStatic1.a and libStatic2.a were independent and everything was okay. But now I added to the code that generates libStatic1.a a dependency on the code that generates libStatic2.a. Therefore, any SO that depends on libStatic1.a now needs to be compiled with libStatic2.a. This is undesirable, because it adds a dependency on libStatic2.a to every build targets that depends on libStatic1.a.

only on libStatic1.a now need to compile their code with libStatic2.a in order for the compilation/runtime to succeed/not crash. This creates an unnecessary coupling and I would like to avoid it.

Therefore, I need to somehow "embed" the object code of libStatic2.a in libStatic1.a. If I would just compile libStatic1.a with all the object files of libStatic2.a (in addition to its own), it will basically contain it but this creates another problem- If some user of libStatic1.a will decide to use libStatic2.a and will link it, he will get a weird "multiple definitions" error. If I could somehow tell the compiler to generate the object files of libStatic2.a with weak symbols (only for the use in libStatic1.a) this would solve the problem- no one will get multiple definitions, and no makefile of all the many SOs that use libStatic1.a will need to change.

My thinking: I know that it is [possible](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (using [GCC/g++ extensions to the C language](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C%20Extensions)) to declare a function with the keyword **__attribute__** and the ***weak*** attribute as following:
`void __attribute__((weak)) foo(int j);`

Is there a way to tell the compiler (g++) to compile an entire compilation unit as "weak", meaning all its global symbols in the symbol table will be considered weak when linking?

**Alternatively, is there a way to tell the *linker (ld)* to consider *all* the symbols of some object file/library as if they are weak?**

Comment: Are you getting symbol conflicts when linking?

Comment: @trojanfoe and Maxim Yegorushkin:
**now** i finished editing my original message to explain my motivation.

Answer (score 2):

Compile it normally and then `objcopy` the object file with `--weaken`.

Answer (score 1):

If your library is small, the simplest way is still to change the declarations by adding manually the `__attribute__((weak))`.

Another possibility might be to ask `g++` to spill the assembly code (with `-S`) and have some (perhaps `awk`or `ed`) script work on it.

You could also code a GCC plugin (assuming your g++ is a 4.6 version) or a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there doesn't appear to be; are there so many weak external functions that it's not practical to set their attributes individually?